# Xamarin gesture recognizer for custom control

Tags: android, events, xamarin.forms, command

I have created a custom control, which contains a Image. So, I need know when user click on the image. I tried to add a TapGestureRecognizer with command, which fired an event. However, this doesn't work. How can I do this?

```
public class PhotoViewer: ContentView
{
   public event Action<object> OnImageClicked;

   public PhotoViewer()
   {
       public PhotoViewer()
       {
           StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();

           IList<View> holders = GeneratePhotoHolders(BackgroundImageCount);
           stackLayout.Children.AddRange(holders);

           this.Content = stackLayout;
       }
   }

    private IList<View> GeneratePhotoHolders(int count)
    {
        List<View> holders = new List<View>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            TapGestureRecognizer OneTapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer()
            {
                NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
                Command = new Command(o => OnImageClicked?.Invoke(o))
            };
            Image image = new Image();
            image.GestureRecognizers.Add(OneTapRecognizer);

            holders.Add(image);
        }

        return holders;
    }
}
```

Inside my MainPage

```
photoViewer.OnImageClicked += (o) => Debug.WriteLine("Clicked");
```

**EDITED**

I have tested event implementation on common ConsoleApp and it is work fine. However, inside this custom control, `OnImageClicked` always `null`

Comment: Is it all the code you have in your constructor?

Comment: I have there custom control initilization too. Сould it has affect?

Comment: I think it will make sense to share with us all the related code. Without it, it will be hard to answer your question.

Comment: With the update you mixed old code and new code that makes it incoherent.

Comment: Oh, I have just deleted TapGestureRecognizer in the top. Now, it is all code, excluding bindable propertyes

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with getter that returns a new instance. I guess what you wanted is to initialize your getter:

```
private TapGestureRecognizer OneTapRecognizer { get;} = new TapGestureRecognizer()
      {
         NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
         Command = new Command<object>(o => OnImageClicked?.Invoke(o))
      };
```

Moreover why a getter if the variable is private?

I guess what your want actually is:

```
public class PhotoViewer: ContentView, IDisposable 
{

       private readonly TapGestureRecognizer _oneTapRecognizer;
       
       public event Action<object> OnImageClicked;
    
       public PhotoViewer()
       {
           _oneTapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer()
          {
             NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
             Command = new Command<object>(o => OnImageClicked?.Invoke(o))
            }
           photoHolder.GestureRecognizers.Add(_oneTapRecognizer);
       }
    
        public void Dispose()
        {
            photoHolder.GestureRecognizers.Remove(_oneTapRecognizer);
        }
   }
```

Comment: It make sense, but `OnImageClicked` never fired, because it always `null` and i don't undestend why. So, I have updated my post, and added more code.